# Create a cocoapod that has a compiled framework as a dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am creating a Cocoapod (`MyPod`) with support for iOS and tvOS that has a framework dependency. I don't have access to the framework code, but do have the compiled framework, lets call it `ThirdParty.framework`. There are different versions of the framework for iOS and tvOS.

I am able to build build `MyPod` target successfully in Xcode directly, and use the generated framework in other projects. To create the pod though, when I run `pod lib lint` it shows an error:

`error: failed to build module 'ThirdParty' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.1.2 (swiftlang-1100.0.278 clang-1100.0.33.9)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)'`

Here's my podspec:

```
 s.name             = 'MyPod'
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   s.name             = 'MyPod'
   s.version          = '0.1.0'
   s.summary          = 'This is MyPod'
   s.description      = <<-DESC
  Provides functionality for ....
                        DESC
   s.static_framework = true
   s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/username/MyPod'
   s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
   s.author           = { 'username' => 'myemail@email.com' }
   s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/username/MyPod.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
   s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'
   s.swift_versions = '5.0'
   s.ios.source_files = 'MyPod/Common/**/*.swift', 'MyPod/Platform/iOS/**/*.swift'
   s.tvos.source_files = 'MyPod/Common/**/*.swift', 'MyPod/Platform/tvOS/**/*.swift'
   s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyPod/Frameworks/ios/universal/ThirdParty.framework'
   s.tvos.vendored_frameworks = 'MyPod/Frameworks/tvos/universal/ThirdParty.framework'
   s.preserve_path = 'MyPod/Frameworks'
end
```

I don't fully understand the error but it seems when i run `pod lib lint` cocoapods is trying to rebuild the framework. So the question is, is there a way to link `ThirdParty.framework` without building it to get around this error?

Comment: You need to have the ThirdParty.framework build with the Swift version tart. Since yours is 5.3, it's saying that the third party one in 5.1.2 should be compiled with 5.3. Can you rebuilt it?

Comment: No we can't rebuild. The framework is from an external client and we don't have the source code.

Comment: I'd use then Xcode 11.2.1 (reinstall it if needed), and least its compiler/command line tools (Xcode/Settings/Locations) choose it.